# ¿Cómo consumir REST API en Angular?

Tags: nodejs, angular

quisiera saer como puedo consumir un api rest  de la siguiente manera pero en angular
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
getproduct() {

    let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('deploy', "pagina.dyndns.org");
params = params.append('resource', "PRODUCT");
params = params.append('superID', "TCABELLO");


    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/puntoventa/api/product/get/`,{ params:params });

  }
```

de esa manera creo que es la equivocada como puedo pasar estos parametros para que me devuelva la respuesta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba realizando la consulta pasando los parametric directamente

```
 return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/puntoventa/api/product/get?deploy=página.dyndns.org&resource=PRODUCT&superID=TCABELLO `);
```